# Delete photo tag from Graph API

Tags: facebook, api, tags, photo

I am trying to create an app that assists users in removing unwanted tags. I've heard a lot of complaining that FB no longer allows public access to the deletion of pictures... Is the same thing going on for tags?

I get `{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call."}}` when I try to do the deletion via

`https://graph.facebook.com/some_photo_id/tags/user_id?access_token=a_valid_access_token&callback=whatever&method=delete&pretty=0&sdk=joey`

I get the same error if I try an AJAX DELETE request or use `FB.api('/pid/tags/uid', 'delete', function(){})`

I have enabled the permissions: user_photos, friends_photos, publish_stream, publish_actions, user_status. Did I forget a certain permission?

I would really appreciate assistance with this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I've been able to upload a photo, and add some random tags to it on C#, but it seems to be impossible to remove them; it is weird because if you use the integrated app in a windows phone for example you can add and remove any tag you want without problems, the only restriction is that obviously you can't remove tags that you didn't create, only this wp integrated feature and the facebook's app in the android devices are capable of that but you'll find that in android devices with the facebook official app it is not posible to delete tags that you create of your friends, just yours.

If you want you can give it a try [here](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) where if you specify a valid photo id and a valid facebook user id you still get:

```
"error": {    
"message": "(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.",
     "type": "OAuthException",
     "code": 3  
}
```

In fact I read in another forum that the applications where only able to delete tags and photos that they create and no more than that, but that was not the case, I uploaded and tagged a photo with my app but when I tried to delete the tags It was not posssible.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Yes, now it's possible (but doesn't work). [Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/#tags).

> You can delete a tag for a particular user in the photo by issuing a
>   HTTP DELETE request to /PHOTO_ID/tags/USER_ID or
>   PHOTO_ID/tags?to=USER_ID.

**OLD**

It is not possible. It is possible only to create or update photo tags. [Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/#tags).

Comment: The documentation you've linked to now lists a delete method as well, although it didn't at the time you posted this answer. However, at the time of writing, the delete method does not work, as noted by Jorge Avila and user2026318.

Answer (score -1):

What about the delete request at the link you provided?

You can delete a tag for a particular user in the photo by issuing a `HTTP DELETE` request to `/PHOTO_ID/tags/USER_ID` or `PHOTO_ID/tags?to=USER_ID`.

Deleting a tag on a photo requires the publish_stream permission and supports the following parameters:

```
Parameter | Description                | Type   | Required
----------------------------------------------------------
to        | USER_ID of the User to tag | string | yes
```

The `USER_ID` can also be provided in URL path (see above)

If the deletion is successful, you get the following return:

```
Description               | Type
-----------------------------------
If the deletion succeeded | boolean
```

Comment: I tried the http delete requests and I still get "Application does not have the capability to make this API call." even with publish_stream, user_photos, and many other permissions added.  This is driving me crazy, does anyone have it working that can provide an example?